# c# MVC + Reflexion: Exposing assembly name

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have Web app project that refers class library. 
Like so:

```
MyWebApp
DatatableLibrary
----- MyDataTableClass.cs
```

In my view, I'm making an ajax call that got exposed MyDataTableClass AssemblyQualifiedName. for ex.:

```
DatatableLibrary.MyDataTableClass, DatatableLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Why? So I can in controller do this trick:

```
public JsonResult DatatableRequest(string className){ Type.GetType(className); //more stuff + response}
```

I feel that there is good risk of exposing valuable informations in class and assembly name in View, am I right? Is there any trick or workaround here?

Answer (score 0):

About the security, I can only think about 2 options:

1. [Strong] Have the current user / current session of who is calling the the controller `DatatableRequest` and check if that user/caller has the permissions to access that assembly.
2. [Weak] Pass a token to the call, and return a `DULL` object if the token isn't correct. By `DULL` I mean an object which is empty or doesn't do anything, or if you want, you can even return a `NULL`

But, why do you need to do this?

I would choose the first option and implement a filter so I can reuse it in different places if needed.

like this:

**Filter**

```
public class ValidateAssemblyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string classNameField = "className";

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Get the field through the helper
        string className = filterContext.GetValue<string>(classNameField); 

        // User 2 doesn't have access to xpto.dll
        if (Membership.CurrentUserId == 2 && className == "xpto.dll")
            AuthorizationHelpers.NoPermissions(filterContext);

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext); // Execute base
    }
}
```

**Helpers**

```
public static class AuthorizationHelpers
{
    public static T GetValue<T>(this ActionExecutingContext filterContext, string Field)
    {
        if (Field != null)
        {
            // Get the value provider for the given field name
            var value = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(Field);

            // If the value provider has an attemped value (value), proceed
            if (value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.AttemptedValue))
            {
                // Get the underlying type of the generic parameter and return the true type: [Nullable<
                Type underType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T);

                // Get the TypeConvert to change string (AttemptedValue) to `T`.
                TypeConverter conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(underType);

                // Create an auxiliar variable that will contain the result.
                T result = default(T);

                // See if the converted can convert the AttemptedValue to `T`
                if (conv.IsValid(value.AttemptedValue))
                    result = (T)conv.ConvertFrom(value.AttemptedValue); // Convert the value

                return result;
            }
        }

        // Return the default of the generic type if the field name doesn't exist.
        return default(T);
    }

    public static void NoPermissions(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Override the result so it returns another action (No permissions action)
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Error/NoPermissions");
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
[ValidateAssembly]
public JsonResult DatatableRequest(string className)
{
    Type.GetType(className);
    //more stuff + response
}
```